# Update the select options with given dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-select

Need to send dynamic (not hardcode) data to a select element.

This code works great in one of my sheets but **doesn't work in the other sheet**.

**The "select" element doesn't get updated with the options I send.**. 
I don't get an error message either.

I've spent a lot of time twitching it and trying to find why but still don't see what's wrong.

p.s. I used a dummy object to send the data for testing purpose.

The html (used [MaterializeCss](https://materializecss.com/select.html) framework)

```js
<select class="icons browser-default" id="selName" onChange ="getNameText();">  
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose week</option>

 <div id = "err"></div>

//select element initialization in framework
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var options = handlers()
  var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
});

function handlers() {

  var success = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addOptions).getNamesForDropdown()
  var failure = google.script.run.withFailureHandler(showError).getNamesForDropdown()

  return;
}

function addOptions(names) {

  var selectTag = document.getElementById("selName") //select tag

     for (var k in names) {        
         var thisID = k;
         var thisText = names[k];
         var option = document.createElement("option"); //creating option        
         option.text = thisText
         option.value = thisID;
         selectTag.add(option);
     }
}

function showError() {

  var err = document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = "There was an error."
}


//get the text of selected option
function getNameText() {

  var sel = document.getElementById("selName")

  var nameText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

  return nameText;
}
```

Dummy object I send:

```js
function getNamesForDropdown() {

  var namesObj = {
    
    one: "blah",
    two: "blahblah"    
  }

  return namesObj;
}
```

Here's the result what I get (on the screen you there's only hardcoded option):

[image]

Comment: Can you update your script in your question for replicating your issue? Because your script is not complete for replicating your issue. For example, what is ``M.FormSelect.init()``? And ``selName`` is ``weeksSel``? So even if your this script was modified, I can't have confidence whether the modified script can resolve your actual issue. By the way, ``google.script.run()`` run with the asynchronous process and this function doesn't return values. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: sorry, updated the post. I return the values from backend with this https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function) and pass them to another function. See the pattern in the link.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. In your current script, I think that an error occurs at ``M.FormSelect.init(elems)``. If ``M.FormSelect.init(elems)`` is removed, the script works. ``{one: "blah", two: "blahblah"}`` is returned from ``getNamesForDropdown()`` after HTML was loaded, and the options are added using the values. And when a value is selected, the selected text is returned from ``getNameText()``. Under this situation, can I ask you about your issue and goal?

Comment: Hmm, I removed it and it didn't work with me, the select disappeared at all.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to correctly your current issue, can you provide your current script for replicating your current issue? If you can do, please add it to your question or update your question. By this, I would like to confirm about your issue. The reason that I couldn't understand the solution of your current issue from your reply comment is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: From your comment I see that you understood right. I also updated the post. The issue: my options not showing in select dropdown.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 1. About ``This code works great in one of my sheets but doesn't work in the other sheet.``, we cannot know the difference between ``one of my sheets`` and ``other sheet`` from your question. 2. About ``Hmm, I removed it and it didn't work with me, the select disappeared at all.``, I commented ``can you provide your current script for replicating your current issue?``. But it seems that your current script doesn't reflect [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452877/update-the-select-options-with-given-dynamic-data#comment99499257_56452877). How about them?

Comment: I apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon. When you provide the information, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Oh sorry I got what you mean, I updated the getNamesForDropdown part at the bottom. But it doesn't change anything - that's the only thing I get from backend here. And here you can see all the html relevant to this situation. Need help)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled it. I added a class "browser-default" to the select and the options got updated. This class comes from MaterializeCss Framework.